# One dimensional edge detection

Tags: image, image-processing, 2d, computer-vision, edge-detection

Instead of edge detection of a 2D image, I would like to detect edges on every single row (i.g. a line) of an image separately. That is detection of edges from an input 1D vector whose values are pixel intensities ranging from 0 to 255 ( image below):
[image]

I would like to detect the major edges as appear in the sample input( image below)
[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. Please if you come across with any more new ideas(1Dimentional edge detections) share that here too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to get to your desired result is to adapt the 2D Canny edge detector as follows (code in Mathematica):

First, compute the spatial derivative using a Gaussian derivative filter, setting the sigma value relative to the scale of the edges you want to detect. Take the absolute value of the result.

```
d = Abs@GaussianFilter[data, {{10, 5}}, 1];
```

Then, determine a threshold automatically to cluster the previous derivative values in two groups (here using Otsu's method).

```
thrd = FindThreshold[d];
```

Then, detect the steps of the derivative values (transitions into/from the "dead band").

```
steps = Flatten@Image`StepDetect[d, thrd]["NonzeroPositions"];
```

At this point you have the ends of the edges:

```
ListLinePlot[data, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Map[Point[{#, data[[#]]}] &, steps]}]
```

[image]

Optionally--it seems that's what you'd like--keep only the lowest ends of the edges. Clustering the data points at the ends of the edges works in this case, but I'm not sure how robust it is.

```
t = FindThreshold@data[[steps]];
steps2 = Select[steps, data[[#]] <= t &];

ListLinePlot[data, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Map[Point[{#, data[[#]]}] &, steps2]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Given the nice contrast of these edges, there is an easy solution that will work robustly: detect all monotonous sequences of pixel values (strictly increasing or decreasing). You will keep the sequences having a total height above a threshold (50 in your case) to reject the noisy peaks.

As a byproduct, you'll get the starting and ending points (not exactly where you expect them though, but this can be improved on if needed).

Barcodes ?

Comment: Not quit exactly, however you may think of it as colored barcode

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking for a particular change in slope - ie a certain change in Y per sample?

Isn't it simply look at the difference in Y between two samples and if it's absolute value changed by more than some limit mark that as an edge?

Comment: No really, it would not be that simple at all. For the refrence look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection (Why edge detection is a non-trivial task)

Comment: @Cgraphics: On the images you posted a simple difference or derivative of gaussian operator should work fine. If you think "it's not that simple at all", please post the actual data you're having trouble with.

Comment: @nikie that is the actual image, however it not as simple as a applying a simple threshold either. We need an accurate detection of edges not just, say, counting them.